# local file access on Chrome for Android

Tags: android, google-chrome

In Chrome, by default, file:// URIs cannot read other file:// URIs. 
In the Windows version you can append --allow-file-access-from-files to the Chrome shortcut as an override, but I haven't figured out a comparable work around on the Android version.

I need to do an AJAX call from a local html file that will access a local JSON file.
Any workarounds on how to allow file access from files for Chrome on Android?

Thanks.

Comment: No way to do this and not clear why you would want this anyway. file:// behavior be on mobile is undefined.

Comment: This is possible in all other browsers on the device... Firefox, Opera, built-in Android browser, etc. We have customers that are not allowed to connect to WWW where simply copying small web app from a DVD would be very easy without actually going through the process of creating an native app for everything.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround could be to make your own web service that run in the background that provides both the webbapp files and the json data file.